# What is the difference between Heroku Postgres DBs HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER and HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I created a new Heroku app, and then attached the Dev Heroku Postgres db to it.
In the app's activity log, I see:

```
v07 : Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD resource 5 minutes ago
v06 : Deploy 076b03a 19 minutes ago
v05 : Add config 19 minutes ago
v04 : Add DATABASE_URL config 19 minutes ago
v03 : Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER resource 19 minutes ago
v02 : Enable Logplex 21 minutes ago
v01 : Initial release 21 minutes ago
```

So the GOLD db must be the Dev version I added. What is AMBER?

Comment: My guess is they are both dev plans, i think the amber was created with your new app, then you added a 2nd one? Might also be helpful? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

Answer (score 4):

When you deployed your app initially, we automatically provision one database for you (a dev) if you need it (we detect for example the `pg` gem in your Gemfile, if this is a ruby app. This would be `HEROKU_POSTGREQL_AMBER`, which we also happened to set as your `DATABASE_URL`

Consequently, you manually provisioned another database, `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD`, presumably via `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql`.

My guess is you're using `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER` because it must be set to the value of `DATABASE_URL`. To verify this, try `heroku config --app <your-app> | grep postgres`. You could also just run `heroku pg:info --app <your-app>` to check all databases installed on your app, and also verify which is your primary (`DATABASE_URL`).

You can then remove the spare with `heroku addons:remove HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR-OF-THE-SPARE-MOST-LIKELY-GOLD>`.